# Java upload zip with entries (BLOB) to Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, zip

I am working on a utility where you zip several MS Office files and then upload it to a Db.

Problem is when I upload zip with 1 entry it works, when 2 or more entries I get an exception (yea some encoding issues here).

```
java.sql.SQLException: Ïðåâûøåí ðàçìåð äàííûõ, ðàçðåøåííûé äëÿ ýòîãî òèïà: 45804
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:187)
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:229)
    at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTCItem.setArrayData(TTCItem.java:99)
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBDataSetImpl.setBytesBindItem(DBDataSetImpl.java:1771)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setItem(OraclePreparedStatement.java:986)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setBinaryStream(OraclePreparedStatement.java:2299)
    at fr.CDb.addArchFile(CDb.java:254)
    at fr.CFr.addZipArch(CFr.java:41)
    at fr.CMain.main(CMain.java:13)
```

My upload code (EXCEPTION TRIGGERS ON cs.setBinaryStream()):

```
public void addArchFile() {
    CDb cb = new CDb();
    OracleConnection conn = cb.getConn();
    OracleCallableStatement cs = null;
    String fileDir = CFr.getFileDir();
    String fileName = CFr.getFileName();
    try {
      //
      File f = new File(fileDir + fileName);
      FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(f);
      FileNameMap fileNameMap = URLConnection.getFileNameMap();
      //
      cs = (OracleCallableStatement)conn.prepareCall("Begin Va_File.Add_File(?, ?, ?, ?, ?); End;");
      cs.setString(1, (String)FilenameUtils.getExtension(fileName)); 
      cs.setString(2, (String)fileNameMap.getContentTypeFor(fileDir + fileName)); 
      cs.setString(3, fileName);
      cs.setBinaryStream(4, in, (int)f.length());
      cs.setInt(5, (int)f.length());
      cs.execute();
      in.close();
      //
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()));
    } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      e.getMessage();
    } finally {
      done(cs);
      done(conn);
    }  
  }
```

My Add_File proc from a package:

```
 Procedure Add_File(
    i_Mime_Type    Varchar2,
    i_Ext          Varchar2,
    i_Name         Varchar2,
    i_Cont         Blob,
    i_Cont_Size    Number
  )
  Is
    v_Id   Integer;
    r_File Va_Arch_Files%Rowtype;
  Begin
    Select Nvl(Max(t.Arch_Id), 0) + 1 Into v_Id From Va_Arch_Files t;
    --
    r_File.Arch_Id        := v_Id;
    r_File.Mime_Type      := i_Mime_Type;
    r_File.Ext            := i_Ext;
    r_File.Name           := i_Name;
    r_File.Cont           := i_Cont;
    r_File.Cont_Size      := i_Cont_Size;
    r_File.Created_By     := 1;
    r_File.Creation_Date  := Sysdate;
    r_File.Update_By      := r_File.Created_By; 
    r_File.Update_Date    := r_File.Creation_Date;
    --
    Insert Into Va_Arch_Files Values r_File;
    --
    Commit;
  Exception When Others Then 
    Rollback;
    Raise_Application_Error(-20000, Sqlerrm); 
  End;
```

I tried both `ZipOutputStream` (Java) and `ZipArchiveOutputStream` (Apache Commons Compress). I suspect zip entries should be parsed somehow and converted to byte[] then to Blob, but I couldn't find anything worthy on the web.

Comment: What is Va_File.Add_File doing?

Comment: By `ZipOutputStream` and `ZipArchiveOutputStream` did you mean `ZipInputStream` and `ZipArchiveInputStream`?

Comment: No, both are outputstreams, I get my file from the server directory. File f = new File() grabs that zip file that has been created on the server.

Comment: I wonder if the 45804 in the error is the size of the zip file. Can you `System.out.println(f.length());`

Comment: yea that is the size of zip containing 2 docx files = 45804 bytes

Comment: Maybe problem not in BLOB , but in column storing size of blob. What is size of `r_File.Cont_Size` column ?

Comment: currently its size is number(20)

Comment: nope not in size, i tried sending there "1", still uploads with 1 entry but fails with 2 entries

Comment: What's the version of oracle? What version of the jdbc driver are you using? Make sure you are using the proper driver version.

Comment: Oracle 11g XE (Production)/Oracle 12c EE (End-User), Oracle Driver classes12.jar (11g)/ojdbc6.jar (12c), JDK 1.8, Netbeans IDE, Thick Client. I tried on both Oracle versions.. makes no difference

Comment: I got it fixed, you were right the issue lies with the drivers. Our kernel people dropped support for classes12.jar on end-user machines and it finally got working. We then changed our production builds consequently. No more classes12.jar.

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

Adapt all connection classes for the new `ojdbc6.jar` driver.

Drop everything regarding the old & discontinued  `classes12.jar`.